# Hubble Constant and Planck Constant

Tags: cosmology, physical-constants

Has there been any effort to understand Hubble's limit as a quantum phenomenon?

It seems like they are suggesting the same thing.

Comment: How does it seem that they are suggesting the same thing?

Comment: You should work on the coherence and comprehendability of your questions...

Answer (score 5):

Hubble's constant is derived from General Relativity, and specifically from the [Friedmann equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations). The parameters needed are all macroscopic e.g. the average density of the universe so it isn't obvious that quantum mechanics plays a role, except of course that General Relativity is probably the large scale limit of some theory of quantum gravity.

Were you thinking of [dark energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_energy)? There have been various suggestions about linking this to the zero point energy of quantum fields, or more recently relating it to local minima in the [String Landscape](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_theory_landscape). However this is all pretty speculative.